# spock test with metaclass.render

Tags: grails, groovy, spock

In order to do integration test of model in render (template), I use metaClass.render to store the model in a map. However, the map seems not work with 'where' block

```
def renderMap
def mmc

def setup() {
    MilestonesMgtController.metaClass.render = { Map map ->
        renderMap = map
    }
    mmc = new MilestonesMgtController()
}

void "create a new milestone"() {
    when:
    mmc.params.newName = 'Written Workshop'
    mmc.params.newDeadlineFT = a
    mmc.params.newDeadlinePT = '4'
    mmc.params.newNotificationFT = '7'
    mmc.params.newNotificationPT = '7'
    mmc.newMilestone()

    then:
    renderMap.template == 'milestoneDetails'
    renderMap.model.errorMessages == b

    where:
    a    |  b
    '4'  |  null                      //first test
    '0'  |  'deadlineFT cannot be 0'  //second test
}
```

the second test in 'where' block fails, it says renderMap is null. The result is same if I change the order between first and second test. It seems that renderMap is null after the first round. Do you know what is wrong with the code? Many thanks!

Comment: Why do you need to mock `render` in integration test? Integration spec is not for this purpose.

Comment: Although I agree this is generally not the way to go, there are scenarios where integration tests are needed for controllers. We used to be able to use the GroovyPagesTestCase base class to handle rendering cases but after Grails 2.3 switched to the new @TestMixin route for integration that hasn't really been replaced with anything that I know of. I guess you could argue that anything you want to integration test in a controller should be moved to a service and mocked.

Comment: @dmahapatro sorry that I am not familiar with Grails/Groovy, I start to use this two weeks ago. Maybe you can point me a proper way to do it. I want to test the model rendering with the template, so as you suggested in my previous post, I used the unit test with Views[]. However my controller has to query from database and also uses services. That's why I moved back to integration test.

Comment: Was there a problem using mocked data and mocked service in unit test?

Comment: @dmahapatro when I use the mocke data by mockDomain([...]).save, the returned data always be [xxx:unsaved]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will really shoot yourself in the foot if you start Class level metaclassing in an integration test. Unlike unit tests, those metaclass changes will not be rolled back and will *infect* your test run with metaclass contamination.

If you really need an integration test, try metaClassing the instance of the controller to prevent contamination. I'm curious if that will fix your problem. Also, I tend to use @Shared for cases like this although I'm not sure it's strictly necessary.

```
@Shared renderMap
@Shared mmc

def setup() {
    mmc = new MilestonesMgtController()
    mmc.metaClass.render = { Map map -> renderMap = map }
}
```